# Pre-parse (cache) printf-style format string

Tags: c++, c++11, printf

When repeatedly calling

> printf/snprintf/fprintf/etc.

with the same format string and it doesn't really make sense to reparse the format string on each call for the argument positions.

Is anyone aware of a library that provides the function of parsing a format string up front and then passing this to a printf-style function, thereby reducing the processing time?

Comment: Did you run into a situation when your profiler pointed to a `printf` as the biggest bottleneck in your code?

Comment: are you sure, that is your biggest problem, or are you optimizing prematurely? What's the scenario?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight ... and this being because of the parsing and not because of the following output.

Comment: Yes, although that aside, the question still remains valid.its a logger.

Comment: It may be possible using some [strings-in-template](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2012/10/using-strings-in-c-template-metaprograms/) and variadic template. But it would be simpler to just use variadic template and remove the formatting string completely.

Answer (score 3):

Most stock printf functions are reasonably efficient, the format string is a single, coherent source as opposed to copious, short buffers, as produced by iostreams and Boot.Format, and in most cases it (the format string) is the bulk of what you are going to copy to the destination buffer. "Parsing" printf formats is fairly cheap, but if you've actually verified that your printf function is a bottleneck and that it's not a result of poor management of printf buffers, then you should also know which formats are expensive.

Frequently, printf/snprintf will show up in sampled profiles because it inevitably involves a fair amount of transfer

```
snprintf(thatBuffer, someSize, "[%u/%u/%u %u:%u:%u.%llu %s:%u] %p %s %f",
    /* a 2-cacheline date object */ date->dy, date->mo, date->yr, date->hr, date->mi, date->sec, date->ms,
    __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, // why didn't you embed those in the format?
    object->ptr,            // another cache line
    message,                // string from somewhere on the heap, page fault,
    floaty                  // floats and doubles are usually expensive
    );
```

and we didn't even use any fancy formatting.

There are several things you can do to optimize printing:

- Write your own, simplified printf with limited masks and try to build sub-buffers coherently.
- Use C++11 variadic templates to avoid 'vsnprintf' forwarding (I've found this can improve performance by insane amounts)

For instance, under GCC 4.8.2, Clang 3.5 and MSVC 2013, the following:

```
template<typename... Args>
int formatText(const char* const fmt, Args&&...)
{
    int len = std::min(snprintf(m_text, m_textSize, fmt, std::forward<Args>(args)...), m_textSize);
    m_text[len] = '\0';
    return len;
}
```

benchmarked 3x faster than the following for me:

```
int inline formatText(const char* const fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    int len = std::min(vsnprintf(m_text, m_textSize, fmt, args), m_textSize);
    va_end(args);
    m_text[len] = '\0'; // assume m_textSize is storage size - sizeof('\0')
    return len;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Boost.Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) parses a format string to create a formatter object, once, which you can then reuse. Although the parsing is cached, it looks like you get multiple intermediate string copies instead, so I doubt it will be faster.

You could gut a `printf` implementation to cache the parsing stage. The only situations when this seems likely to produce a significant saving are:

- if there are long un-formatted literal strings which you can memcpy instead of copying character-by-character
- lots of explicit widths and precisions which are converted to integers

Fundamentally, `printf` strings are designed to be pretty cheap to parse, and it isn't clear many intermediate formats will be better.

Comment: Thanks. Boost.Format is very slow in a lot of benchmarks published online. I'll give it a go though.